# CSS tooltip positioning after a certain area

Tags: css, css-selectors, tooltip

I made a tool tip for the periodic table I'm making and still can't figure out how to adjust it so you hover on a certain one and it displays on a different side.

```
a.tooltip
{
    outline:none; 
}
a.tooltip strong 
{
    line-height:30px;
}
a.tooltip:hover 
{
    text-decoration:none;
} 
a.tooltip span 
{
    display:none;
    line-height:16px;
    margin-left:26px;
    margin-top:-30px;
    padding:14px 20px;
    width:450px; 
    z-index:10;
}
a.tooltip:hover span
{ 
    background:#218C24; 
    border:1px solid #000000;
    color:#111;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
}
    /*CSS3 extras*/
a.tooltip span
{
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #707062;
}
```

Here's the actual CSS part and I just need it to postion to the right after a certain post. How do I fix this? And I would perfer to keep it in nothing but CSS.

Heres the 
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Apparatus17/ckx59428/)
or for the full screen view
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Apparatus17/ckx59428/embedded/result/)

Please help
Thank you for your time as always.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: the links above should take you righ to the cod in jsfiddle

Comment: i want to switch it after the 9th group to display on the let instead of right so it doesn't force the page to grow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with the following CSS which would help you achieve what you're trying to do. It's a combination of different `psuedo-selector`'s and it successfully changes the position of the tool-tip's to the right side for any elements in the periodic table after and including the 9th group. The good thing is that your HTML structure remains unchanged.

```
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4) a div span, tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(n+4) a div span, tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(n+4) a div span, tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(n+10) a div span, tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(n+10) a div span, tr:nth-child(7) td:nth-child(n+10) a div span, tr:nth-child(8) td:nth-child(n+10) a div span {
     margin-left: -515px;
}
```

Here's the link to a working [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cna2kkdg/embedded/result/).

Comment: Thank you very much works very nicely how did you have it specify the group names?

Comment: @apparatus17 Since you didn't have any common class on the `span` tags for elements after and including the 9th group in the periodic table which we could've targeted using CSS to change the `margin-left` value of it, I have used the `nth-child` psuedo selectors to target them more simply. For example, let's take this selector `tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4) a div span`; `tr:nth-child(2)` specifies that we want to only target the second row (the one containing Hydrogen and Helium`, `td:nth-child(4)` specifies that we want to target only the 4th `td` which in your periodic table is the........

Comment: ........`18th` column. Next, `a div span` specifies that we want to target the `span` tag inside the `div` which is wrapped with an `<a>` tag. So in short, using `tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4) a div span`, we're specifying that we want to target the `<span>` tag in the 4th `td` which is inside the 2nd `tr` (second row). You can read more about `nth-child` psuedo-selector over here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child